# My Jira plugin keeps failing

Tags: java, jira

I'm following [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+Project+Template) tutorial on creating a simple project template. I've ran through the tutorial several times and I always get the same error. After I run `atlas-run` in the directory it spends about 5 minutes setting everything up to eventually give me this error:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ___ FAILED PLUGIN REPORT _____________________
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1 plugin failed to load during JIRA startup.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   'com.atlassian.plugins.tutorial.my-project-template-tests' - 'my-project-template'  fail
ed to load.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           Cannot start plugin: com.atlassian.plugins.tutorial.my-project-template-tests
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]                   Unresolved constraint in bundle com.atlassian.plugins.tutorial.my-projec
t-template-tests [137]: Unable to resolve 137.0: missing requirement [137.0] package; (package=com.example.plugins.tutor
ial)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           It was loaded from C:\work\my-project-template\target\jira\home\plugins\installe
d-plugins\my-project-template-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ******************************************************************************************
************************
```

---

I checked the [corresponding bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/jira-project-templates-tutorial) and noticed both mine and theirs appear very similar bar from a few version number differences. Are the tutorials out of date? I can't see anything in my project to do with `my-project-template-tests`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clear the plugin cache

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-27314